# I am trying to get a date in mysql that is after January 1st 2016

Tags: mysql

My query is

```
SELECT * FROM fitnessLogentries
WHERE RawDistanceCourse = "OW"
AND STR_TO_DATE(fitnesslogentries.Date, '%Y-%m-%d') > STR_TO_DATE(2016-01-01, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

My dates in the database are stored as 2012-01-15 but it keeps returning dates with 2014 in the year

Comment: Date literals are like strings, you need quotes around them - `'2016-01-01'`. Also `STR_TO_DATE` is not necessary in this case.

Comment: @Vatev you should post this as an answer